# Pass a list of types as Generic parameter

Tags: c#

I was wondering if I could pass a List of types as generic parameter.
I have a class which needs to get indefinite number of types and work with them.
**something like this:**

```
class o<TTypeCollection>
{
    private void someMethod()
    {

        repository.Save < TTypeCollection.First() > (MyCollectionViewSource.CurrentItem as TTypeCollection.First());

    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at Tuple in .net 4.0

Comment: There is no way to do template meta-programming in C#, if that's what you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do template meta-programming in C# the C++ style, but you can do it using reflection:

```
private void someMethod() {
    var genericSave = repository // This can be done during initialization
        .GetType()
        .GetMethods()
        .Where(m => m.Name == "Save" && m.IsGenericMethodDefinition);
    var t = MyCollectionViewSource.CurrentItem.GetType();
    genericSave
        .MakeGenericMethod(new[] {t})
        .Invoke(new object[] {MyCollectionViewSource.CurrentItem});
}
```